# Exporting Evernote notes with Siri Shortcuts

Tags: evernote, sirishortcuts

I'm writing a Siri Shortcut to export notes from Evernote to another app. But I'm having a devil of a time figuring out how to do it. When I invoke the shortcut from the iOS share sheet, it sends a link like this to Shortcuts: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s120/sh/3e0ec717-211f-42a0-0327-f64a2337ae8f/bb4a73c5eb5c46d745fe2cda1b700570 . The problem is, the page that that link goes to seems unscrapeable. I can't figure out how to get any information out of it other than the Last Updated date.

The Evernote Get Notes action is no help, because there's no way to pass any useful information to it from that link, as far as I can tell.

Shortcuts supports [APIs](https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/request-your-first-api-apd58d46713f/ios), but I can't see how to use that to get the information I want without building an app. Maybe there's a way, but I can't see it.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? Please help!